# SQL-Group by ID´s from tables

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have 2 tables let's say

- Orders(order_id,etc...) and
- order_items(order_id,...)

I want to get an overview of how many orders have x amount of items by grouping the id from orders with the x amount of ids from order items

So lets say atm I have this scenario:

orders:

| order_id | ??? | ??? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | Pending |
| 33 | 3 | Pending |
| 44 | 3 | Pending |
| 22 | 2 | Pending |
| 444 | 4 | Pending |

order_items:

| order_id | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 7 | 32 | 132 | 469,99 |
| 22 | 5 | 192 | 124 | 519,99 |
| 22 | 7 | 27 | 92 | 800,74 |
| 33 | 11 | 6 | 128 | 849,99 |
| 33 | 10 | 95 | 106 | 109,99 |
| 33 | 5 | 271 | 148 | 549,59 |
| 44 | 9 | 284 | 138 | 54,99 |
| 44 | 8 | 174 | 117 | 798,26 |
| 44 | 6 | 131 | 34 | 279,99 |
| 44 | 11 | 271 | 58 | 549,59 |
| 444 | 9 | 284 | 138 | 54,99 |
| 444 | 8 | 174 | 117 | 798,26 |
| 444 | 6 | 131 | 34 | 279,99 |
| 444 | 11 | 271 | 58 | 549,59 |

With this query:

```
SELECT  count(o.order_id) as ORDER_count,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM order_items  ol
        WHERE o.order_id = ol.order_id) AS ORDER_ITEMS_count
FROM orders o, order_items  ol
 WHERE o.order_id = ol.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id,ol.order_id;
```

I'm getting:

| ORDER_COUNT | ORDER_ITEMS_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

and i'm expecting something like:

| ORDER_COUNT | ORDER_ITEMS_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

Can you please point out what am I missing?

Thankx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get an overview of how many orders have x amount of items by grouping the id from orders with the x amount of ids from order items

First select all orders and count their items. Then use this result to count how many orders share a number of items.

```
SELECT number_of_items, COUNT(*) AS how_many_orders
FROM
(
  SELECT o.order_id, COUNT(oi.order_id) as number_of_items
  FROM orders o
  LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items ON oi.order_id = o.order_id
  GROUP BY o.order_id
) orders_with_item_counts
GROUP BY number_of_items
ORDER BY number_of_items;
```

If every order has at least one item (which seems likely), you can change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Another perspective: an `order` *should* always has one or more `order_items`. Therefore, you could query `order_items` table alone. The query would run faster.

Comment: @JHH: That is true. Thank you for this suggestion. The subquery would just have to be `SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_items FROM order_items GROUP BY order_id`. That would be preferable.